# In JavaScript, is there a way to retrieve the content-type of a URL without retrieving the entire file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-headers, content-type

I would like to determine if a given URL is an image without relying on the file's extension. In JavaScript, is there a way to get a URL's HTTP response headers without retrieving the entire contents of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an http HEAD. This is covered in [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript/260117#260117)

> The HEAD method is identical to GET
>   except that the server MUST NOT return
>   a message-body in the response. The
>   metainformation contained in the HTTP
>   headers in response to a HEAD request
>   SHOULD be identical to the information
>   sent in response to a GET request.
>   This method can be used for obtaining
>   metainformation about the entity
>   implied by the request without
>   transferring the entity-body itself.
>   This method is often used for testing
>   hypertext links for validity,
>   accessibility, and recent
>   modification.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html